# How to roll back XML file in case of exception in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I am creating XML file in C# and write data in it. But in case f exception the file should roll back. But in case of exception, file is generated with incomplete format and data. I just want that when exception generate the file should not be generated. i am using below code to generate file

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(strFileName))
{
 writer.WriteStartElement("Head");//Start Head
 writer.WriteElementString("Date", dtm.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff"));
 writer.WriteEndElement();//End Head
 writer.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Just wrap it in `try...catch` and in `catch` delete the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *simplest* approach is to just build the whole document up to start with in-memory, and then only write it at the very end. That will almost certainly lead to simpler code even leaving aside the "don't write invalid date" side of things. The only downside is if you want to write an enormous file which you don't want in memory first.

Personally I would recommend using LINQ to XML - and using *its* conversions for other types, so you might use:

```
element.Add(new XElement("Date", dtm));
```

... which would use a *correct* XML date/time format rather than the one you've currently got (which uses `hh` instead of `HH`; see my [blog post on date/time text conversions](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/05/05/common-mistakes-in-datetime-formatting-and-parsing/) for more information about similar common mistakes).

Comment: Absolutely agree with: *correct XML data/time format*

Comment: But i just want to know that is there any way to roll back XML file in case of  exception. If there is any way please help me

Comment: @AlinaDilshad: If you've already written to the file, no - you'd basically want to copy or move the original file somewhere else before writing. There's nothing XML-specific about that. But as I say, if you delay writing *anything* until you've prepared the whole document, then if an exception occurs while preparing it, you won't have written anything - so that's the simplest way of achieving the "don't destroy the old file" behaviour you want, isn't it?